# Get a range of months using moment with start month and end month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using a [moment library](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and I would like to use it for getting an array of string months, with the starting date and the end date. So, for example when I have two dates:

```
const from = moment('2018-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMMM');
  const to = moment('2018-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMMM');
```

How can I then get the range of months as a string array, that would then look like this for the given dates:

```
['May', 'June', 'July']
```

Is there a way we can achieve this with moment, and what would be the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [moment.months](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) and slice it to get only needed months

```js
var months = moment.months();
console.log(JSON.stringify(months))

console.log(JSON.stringify(months.slice(4,7)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Kindly, find the below format for moment.

```
var fromDate = moment('2018-05-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
var toDate = moment('2018-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
var monthData = [];

while (toDate > fromDate || fromDate.format('M') === toDate.format('M')){

monthData.push(fromDate.format('MMMM'));
fromDate.add(1,'month');

}
console.log(monthData); // Output ["May", "June", "July"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a solution without moment.js.

Month names are available in the browser default language using *toLocaleString*. To get the names for months from the 3rd to 5th months inclusive, slice them from the array, e.g.

```js
/* Return array of month names for month number range in the
 * browser default language.
 * E.g. 3,5 returns ['March','April','May] with default language English
 * Assumes Gregorian calendar, 12 months in year. If input is invalid,
 * returns an empty array
 *
 * @param {number|string} [startMonth=1] - calendar month number
 * @param {number|string} [endMonth=12]  - calendar month number
 * @returns {string[]} Array of month names from startMonth to endMonth inclusive.
 */
var getMonthNames = (function () {
  var months = new Array(12).fill(0).map((v,i)=>
    new Date(2000,i).toLocaleString(undefined,{month:'long'})
  );
  return function(startMonth=1, endMonth=12) {
    return isNaN(+startMonth) || isNaN(+endMonth)? [] :
           months.slice(--startMonth, endMonth);
  }
}());

// Example
[['03', '03'], // Single month
 ['06'],       // Month to end of year
 [],           // Month 1 to 12
 ['01', '09'], // Month 1 to month 9
 ['foo']       // Erroneous input
].forEach(args => 
  console.log(`${args.toString()}: ${getMonthNames(...args).join(', ')}`)
);
```

Creating the month name list is a little expensive, but it only runs once and it only needs 12 Dates so trivial.

It needs better error handling, e.g. check `start <= end`, `0 < start < 13`, `0 < end < 13`, `start` and `end` are integers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the month range in this format:

```
"2022-12-11T00:00:00+01:00 2022-12-17T23:59:59+01:00"
```

The following code would do the trick.

```
const start = moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week').format();   
const end = moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week').format();
```

I hope this was helpful.